# How to cast FQCN enum case into enum instance in PHP?

Tags: php, enums

I have the following code:

```php
enum Suit: string
{
    case Hearts = 'H';
    case Diamonds = 'D';
    case Clubs = 'C';
    case Spades = 'S';
}

$enumClass = '\Suit';

$hearts = $enumClass::from('\Suit::Hearts');

var_dump($hearts);
```

Which results in

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ValueError: "\Suit::Hearts" is not a valid backing value for enum "Suit"
```

How can I cast human-readable enum strings such as `EnumName::enumCase` into BackedEnum?

Is there some way to call some `get_enum_from_fqcn('\Namespace\Some\Enum::EnumCase')` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone still needs an answer with this. The value that is supposed to go in from is 'H'

```
$hearts = Suit::from('H');
```

If you want it based on the name you could use https://github.com/henzeb/enumhancer, as it allows you to do just that.

```
enum Suit: string
{
    use EnumHancer;

    case Hearts = 'H';
    case Diamonds = 'D';
    case Clubs = 'C';
    case Spades = 'S';
}
```

And then you can just do:

```
Suite::make('Hearts');
```

This will also be helpful with UnitEnums, as you won't be needing values to do it.